# Running a script manually vs running in cron

Tags: perl, cron, aix

Im experiencing issue with running my Perl script using cron job in AIX server.
I have 3 Perl scripts that writes to the same file and it is running simultaneously. My issue is when I do manual testing of running each script manually, the output file is okay. But when I let the cron job run the script simultaneously the output is not the expected. My question is, is there a known issue with different cron job modifying the same file? Im doing this in AIX server by the way if it helps.

Comment: Of course there can be issues with two processes modifying the same resources (whether file or something else).

Comment: Wow, I remember you 6 years ago asking my very first perl question here. Anyway, can you suggest what I do?

Comment: @ikegami please help me lol

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Use a lock?

Comment: Hi @ikegami Thanks a lot, yes locking was the way to do it. I used flock

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Apparently the answer was obvious and simple than what I expected. I used `flock` to lock the file while one job writes to it.